# Vocabulary: an event, usually an unplesant one, that might or might not happen

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

I kept searching for an English word whose definition I remember,  but not the specific term. I have searched but cannot not find it. This is the definition:

> an event, usually an unpleasant one, that might or might not happen in the future

Could you give me some hints?

Comment: Please, correct the spelling of "unplesant" in your title. Come to think of it, that is how the word ought to be spelled/spelt, but I find the misspelling, unpleAsant to read :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the word '**contingency**'. Here's the second of two senses listed on Merriam-Webster's online dictionary:

a.) An event (as an emergency) that may, but is not certain to occur

b.) Something liable to happen as an adjunct to or a result of something else

To be honest, I'm not familiar with sub-sense 'b', and while M-W seems to specify possible (but not certain) emergencies, I've found myself using 'contingency' to refer to minor hiccups and set-backs.

Also, note that 'contingency' also refers to provisions made to address such (possible but not certain) events. Strangely, that sense is not mentioned on M-W, but is listed in the Oxford Dictionary (10th edition; page 307).

Comment: +1 Sorry. Was searching and did not see your post until after I answered.

Comment: http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/contingency. Thanks so much @D.M.Davidson :D

Answer (score 2):

**Presentiment** *An intuitive feeling about the future, esp. one of foreboding* And *An emotional response that can only be described as precognitive, such as a feeling of dread before an impending disaster*.

Words with similar meanings: *boding, foreboding, premonition, presage*
[TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/presentiment)

Comment: Wow, these are excellent suggestions. I hadn't even thought of these. A very comprehensive answer.